# Custom audio Player in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, audio

is their any public api or code who add to my view a custom audio player, i just give the audio path from the array and they play they also have functionalities like forward, rewind, pause, next track, previous track, etc...

Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate questions [AVAudioPlayer - playing multiple audio files, in sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621182/avaudioplayer-playing-multiple-audio-files-in-sequence) [How to play multiple audio files using AVAudioPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744826/how-to-play-multiple-audio-files-using-avaudioplayer) [Play multiple audio files using AVAudioPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586284/play-multiple-audio-files-using-avaudioplayer) [...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=play+multiple+audio+in+ios+)

Comment: thanks sorry i didn't find before thanks for help by link reference.. thanks soo much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apple's document, there is some sample code for playing music.

first one :[avTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008636-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

another :
[AddMusic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845)